# break array as a string

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array:-

```
Array ( [6] => 1 [6(HL)] => 3 [5] => 1 [7(HL)] => 2 )
```

How to break it and echo as like this:-

```
2(6), 3(6(HL)), 1(5), 2(7(HL))
```

I have try to use implode to break it as a string, but this is what result I get:-

```
2, 3, 1, 2
```

any idea on this?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: I assume you mean the output should be `1(6), 3(6(HL)), 1(5), 2(7(HL))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assume your array is $arr :

```
$output = '';
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
  $output .= $v . '(' . $k . ')' . ', ';
}
$output = substr($output, 0, strlen($output)-2);
echo $output;
```

Comment: You can use `rtrim($output, ', ');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = implode(', ', array_map(function($a, $b) {
   return "$b($a)"; 
}, array_keys($a), array_values($a)));
```

Or

```
$s = '';
foreach ($a as $key => $val)
{
  if ($s) $s .= ', ';
  $s .= "$val($key)";
}
```